# Input redirection problems in C++ when writing

Tags: c++, linux

Hello I can read a file perfectly using dup2 but am having trouble when writing to a file and adding to it with these commands:

```
shell: ls >+ lsout
shell: cat lsout
```

Here is the C++ code that is handling the dup2 for write:

```
else if(write == true)
            {
                int fd = open(rCommand[1],O_WRONLY | O_APPEND);
                dup2(fd, 1);
                close(fd);
                execvp(substrings[0], substrings);
            }
```

Substrings array holds the arguments made in the command line and rCommand[1] is the file name of what is trying to be opened or written to.

My understanding is that ls >+ lsout is suppose to create an empty file called lsout but instead when executing only lists items in the current directory. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Could you edit your question with a clearer statement of the expected vs. actual behavior?

Answer (score 0):

well one thing I found out after running `ls >+ lsout` is that it creates a file called `+` and not `lsout`:

`$ ls >+ lsout`
`ls: cannot access 'lsout': No such file or directory`

Therefore, `cat lsout` inevitably throws an error:

`$ cat lsout cat: lsout: No such file or directory`

So I guess this needs to be solved first before moving on.
Also, on further research, I found that the `execvp(substrings[0], substrings);` statement might be wrong as `execvp()` [takes](https://linux.die.net/man/3/execvp) *generally* the first argument as the pointer to the file we are dealing with, but my inference is that `substrings[0]` might hold the command we executed instead of the file name.

And, also just like @aschepler said, please try posting a more descriptive question accompanied by error messages and side-effects as it is helpful for someone trying to solve your problem :)

Best.